# How to get the orders Firestore based on the ZIP Codes that are belong to users in Kotlin?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Following is the structure of my `Firestore` database.

Collection 'users' contain user information where the document name is same as the user ID. Every user will have Zip Codes. In the below screenshot user ID ending with 'O03' has three Zip Codes (123456, 369852, 478965)

[image]

Collection 'orders'. Whenever a customer places an order, it will contain the user's ID and ZIP Code.

[image]

There may be many orders which have the same ZIP Codes. What I want to do is, get the orders which contain ZIP Code that belong to the user, ZIP Code in the orders should match any three (in the given example) of the ZIP Code that the user has. Users can have many ZIP Codes and each user will have a different number of ZIP Codes.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: You might have to store the ZIP codes in an array. It looks like a string to me

Comment: Could you help me with it?